# Creating for loop vector for coefficient in time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

Perhaps I have two values where m=5 and r=3. I am trying to get a vector that has 5 values. When j<=r-1, it must follow the equation (m-r)(j+1). When j>r, it must follow the equation r(m-j-1).

I wrote the following code:

```
    returns = function(m,r){
    vector = numeric(m)
    for(j in 0:m-2){
        if(j <= (r-1)){
          vector[j] = (m-r)*(j+1)
        }
        if(j >= r){
          vector[j] = r*(m-j-1)}}
        print(vector)
        j=j+1}
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
    2,4,6,3,0
```

What I get in return is:

```
    4,6,3,0,0
```

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The index for j must begin with 1 because in R all vectors are based from  1, not 0.

2) The rules give are in terms of j - so adjusted the rules to account for j being 1-based

```
returns = function(m,r){
  vector = numeric(m)
  for(j in 1:m-1){
    if(j < r){
      vector[j] = (m-r)*(j)
      }
    if(j >= r){
      vector[j] = r*(m-j-1)
      }
    }
  print(vector)
  }

returns(5,3)
```